# Como remover o tratamento de um DateTimePicker

Tags: c#

Utilizo o componente DateTimerPicker para utilizar o caledário e setar a data, mas gostaria de remover os tratamentos do componente, pois dificulta a utilização do usuário, já dei uma otimizada, mas queria melhorar.

Comment: Quais tratamentos?

Comment: O tratamento default dele, por exemplo se eu digito 31 no mês 02 ele seta automaticamente 28

Comment: Esse tratamento também ocorre quando o ano é bissexto?

Comment: Estamos falando de Windows Forms?

Comment: Se você quer remover estes tratamentos, porque simplesmente não usa um MaskedTextBox? Não seria mais útil, ou até mais fácil?

Comment: @BrunoRodrigues resolveu o problema ai?

Comment: "Resolvi", tive que criar uma classe override utilizando um MaskedBox e o próprio DateTimePicker, ficou uma beleza!

Answer (score 0):

No evento Load use isto:

```
dt.CustomFormat = " ";
dt.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;

private void dtData_Reserva_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    dtData_Reserva.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    dtData_Reserva.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
}
```